# how using sed can I remove all chars in a line after a given position until a "."?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, aix

how using sed can I remove all chars in a line after a given position until a "." ?
Example:

This is the original line:

```
VARIABLELONGFILENAME.20111205.122300
```

This is what I want: Remove everything starting on position 8 until last char before first ".".

```
VARIABL.20111201.122300
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^\(.......\)[^.]*\./\1./'
```

Comment: or may be this - `sed 's/^\(.\{7\}\)[^.]*\./\1./'`